# dask.async.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]

Tags: python, amazon-s3, dask

I am fetching json data from s3, but keeping running into SSL error 50% of the times. Each s3 bucket contains 500 json files which I am reading into a dask bag.

```
import dask.bag as db
text = db.read_text("s3://path/to/bucket/*.json")
text = text.map(json.loads).compute()
```

I then iterate over the list, processing each element

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 69, in <module>
    parse_bag(text.map(json.loads).compute(), args.flightUUID, pickle.load(open(args.inPickle, "rb")), args.outDumpPath.rstrip("/"))
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 86, in compute
    return compute(self, **kwargs)[0]
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 179, in compute
    results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/multiprocessing.py", line 83, in get
    queue=queue, get_id=_process_get_id, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 484, in get_async
    raise(remote_exception(res, tb))
dask.async.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1754)

Traceback
---------
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 267, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 248, in _execute_task
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 248, in _execute_task
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 248, in _execute_task
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 245, in _execute_task
    return [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in arg]
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 248, in _execute_task
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 249, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/bytes/s3.py", line 145, in s3_open_file
    return s3.open(s3_path, mode='rb')
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 212, in open
    return S3File(self, path, mode, block_size=block_size)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 680, in __init__
    self.size = self.info()['Size']
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 686, in info
    return self.s3.info(self.path)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 303, in info
    files = self._lsdir(parent, refresh=refresh)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 226, in _lsdir
    for i in it:
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 102, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 174, in _make_request
    return self._method(**current_kwargs)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 278, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 561, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 117, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 146, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 219, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 266, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 314, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/hmanjunatha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 356, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
```

Comment: I'm curious, are you able to use `boto3` directly?

Comment: @MRocklin Let me try getting the files using boto3